# Can I have two shebang lines, one for python and one for python3?

Tags: python, linux, shebang

I have a script that I am running on multiple Linux OSs. The shebang line of my script is:

`#!/usr/bin/python`

When I came across CentOS 8, this doesn't work as I get the following:
"-bash: ./sysinfo-snapshot.py: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

And as a workaround I can change the shebang line to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

and this would 100% solve the issue.

However, what I'm looking for is to have my script try the first shebang line, and if it didn't work, to try the second line, as in, 2 first lines in the code would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Is this possible?
Is there a way to support both python and python3 for the script? As in first try the first shebang line, if it didn't work try th second line.

Things I tried to far:
I tried changing the shebang line to: `#!/usr/bin/env python`
But it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you run it as `python foo.py` or `python3 foo.py` instead of `path/to/foo.py`? The shebang just provides the default interpreter when the script is run directly.

Comment: In any case, try `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead. That's more idiomatic.

Comment: Does the script support Python 2? If not, don't use `python`, use `python3`. See [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/).

Comment: What problems have you encountered when you tried to use the she-bang line `#!/usr/bin/env python`?

Answer (score 8):

You could just not have a shebang and execute your script with the appropriate python binary; e.g.

```
$ python3 yourscript.py
```

or

```
$ python yourscript.py
```

And you don't need executable permission for your script.

So to make it portable, use a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -x /usr/bin/python3 ]; then
  /usr/bin/python3 yourscript.py
else
  /usr/bin/python yourscript.py
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

While I would suggest always using `python3` or a separate wrapper script as detailed in the other answers, it is in fact technically possible to have the Python script serve as its own wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
"""": 
if type python3 > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    exec python3 "$0" "$@"
elif type python > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    exec python "$0" "$@"
else
    echo >&2 "Python not installed"
fi
exit 1
""" #"

print("Hello World")
```

When run as a Python script, it'll just run as a regular Python script. When run as a shell script, it'll re-invoke itself with python3 or python.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. The shebang line is the first line of the script. There can only be one first line.

Answer (score 2):

Conforming to POSIX, the `execve(2)` system call only has to look at the *first line* of a script for a `#!`-line. So using more than one `#!`-line shouldn't work.

According to [PEP-394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), on UNIX, `python2` should exist when a 2.x version of Python is installed, and `python3` should exist when a 3.x version of Python is installed.

It is up to the OS distributor to decide if a `python` command is present, and if so which version it envokes.
So on UNIX, the is *no guarantee* that `python` will exist.

So I would suggest the following;

- If your script supports Python 3, change the shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. If this works on all Linux versions you're using, this is the preferred solution.
- If that doesn't work, make your script into the console script of a python package with a `setup.py`. That will ensure a proper shebang-line on installation.

(PEP-394 encourages script distributers to foist the use of virtual environments onto users, which IMO is an unnecessary complication for those that do not need to have different versions of a module installed.)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.